# Using a backreference at the beginning of a pattern in an apache rewrite rule

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm currently translating a website from english to spanish. I want to use a rewrite rule that can put the current language at the beginning of the url, just after the domain. Example:

current url without rewrite rules:
http://www.example.com/sample_subdirectory/?language=spanish

objective:
http://www.example.com/spanish/sample_subdirectory/

At the time of this writing, I have all my php files rewritten as if they were subdirectories (such as example.com/something.php to example.com/something/) so there's no problem there. My objective though is to see if there's a way to rewrite the url so that instead of displaying the language GET variable, it displays "/spanish/something/something_else/etc/"; The goal is to not have to do an individual rewrite rule for every url just for the spanish translations, but rather append that /spanish/ subdirectory towards the beginning of the url. I tried to figure out how to use the metacharacters but I don't think I was doing it right. Here's what I tried (I'm pretty sure this is done so wrong :/ )

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=(spanish)$
RewriteRule ^/spanish/(.*)$ /$1?id=%1

I'm still kinda new at rewrite rules, I only know basic stuff, I'm definitely not a web server administrator so I wouldn't know how to implement what I'm going for. Hopefully it's possible to do this. Ironically, I could have probably finished typing simple rewrite rules instead of spending an hour trying to do this but oh well :P

Answer (score 0):

Based on the example you give above, the following should do what you want:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^language=spanish$
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /spanish/%1?
```

The RewriteCond causes the RewriteRule to be run only when the query string is "language=spanish".

The RewriteRule saves the directory from the original URL and appends it to the directory "/spanish/". The ? at the end removes the query string.

Comment: Thanks for helping me out. Unfortunately, this code didn't get the result I was looking for. However, the explanation that you gave me about the rewrite condition and the way you set up the actual rewrite rule allowed me to see what I had to do. I had to remove the RewriteCond altogether, remove the /spanish from the right side and add it to the pattern, and from there just add the GET variable.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to bobdye's insight, I realized I had to remove the condition altogether and tweak the RewriteRule to look like this:

```
RewriteRule ^/subdirectory/spanish/(.*)$ /subdirectory/$1?language=spanish
```

Note: /subdirectory is a folder inside a virtual server (localhost) that I have running on my laptop.

As you can see, I had to place the /spanish/ directory in the pattern and whatever subdirectory was under that I would use as a back reference to the actual link, then I would just append the GET variable language=spanish to the end of the link. I'll still need to test to make sure that this works for any number of subheadings under /spanish/ but this definitely solved my problem.